# If key is not there remove those dicts in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dictss = [{'country': 'USA'},
          {'country': 'USA'},
          {'name': 'stuart',
           'country': 'USA'},
          {'name': 'tom',
           'country': 'USA'}]
```

If key `name` is not there then have to remove the dicts which does have the key `name`

expected output:

```
[{'name': 'stuart',
  'country': 'USA'},
 {'name': 'tom',
  'country': 'USA'}]
```

Comment: `[x for x in dictss if 'name' in x]`

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) with a filter of `if 'name' in d.keys()`:**

```
dictss = [d for d in dictss if 'name' in d.keys()]

print(dictss)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'stuart', 'country': 'USA'}, {'name': 'tom', 'country': 'USA'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just consider the dictionaries that have `name` as a key using a list comprehension

```
>>> res = [d for d in dictss if 'name' in d]
>>> res
[{'name': 'stuart', 'country': 'USA'}, {'name': 'tom', 'country': 'USA'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
[i for i in dictss if "name" in i]
```